# hide a component inside BrowserRouter in React when i move to a new route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So i have a layout like this:

```
             <BrowserRouter>
                 <div className='App'>
                     <MainHeader />
                     <Homepage />
                     <Route exact path='/' component={Placeholder} />
                     <Route path='/placeholder' component={Placeholder} />
                     <Route path='/address_checker' component={Address_Checker} />
                     <Route path='/availability_checker' component={Availability_Checker} />
                     <Route path='/usage_checker' component={Usage_Checker} />
                     <Route path='/device_checker' component={Device_Checker} />
                     <Route path='/payment_checker' component={Payment_Checker} />
                     <Route path='/result' component={Result} />

                     <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                 </div>
             </BrowserRouter>
```

When I route to any other path besides '/', I want to hide the Homepage component. However, I have no idea how to do this, and my google search has proved fruitless.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to display the component `Homepage` only on path `/` and nowhere else, change your prop `component` to `render` and render `Placeholder` and `Homepage`.

Or Create a Component which renders both and pass that as component.

[Doc for render props.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#render-func)

```js
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className='App'>
        <MainHeader />
        <Route exact path='/' render={props => (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Homepage/>
                <Placeholder/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )}/>
        <Route path='/placeholder' component={Placeholder} />
        <Route path='/address_checker' component={Address_Checker} />
        <Route path='/availability_checker' component={Availability_Checker} />
        <Route path='/usage_checker' component={Usage_Checker} />
        <Route path='/device_checker' component={Device_Checker} />
        <Route path='/payment_checker' component={Payment_Checker} />
        <Route path='/result' component={Result} />

        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score -2):

> When I route to any other path besides '/', I want to hide the
>   Homepage component. However, I have no idea how to do this, and my
>   google search has proved fruitless.

Hello. Your architecture is flawed.

```
        <BrowserRouter>
             <div className='App'>
                 <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage} />
                 <Route path='/placeholder' component={Placeholder} />
                 <Route path='/address_checker' component={Address_Checker} />
                 <Route path='/availability_checker' component={Availability_Checker} />
                 <Route path='/usage_checker' component={Usage_Checker} />
                 <Route path='/device_checker' component={Device_Checker} />
                 <Route path='/payment_checker' component={Payment_Checker} />
                 <Route path='/result' component={Result} />

                 <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
             </div>
         </BrowserRouter>
```

Try this. Just have the routing component be a child of `MainHeader` so that the header is active everywhere. Same for footer etc.

Comment: What if there are items in header and footer that should listen on routing?